# Python p value from t-statistic giving nan

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, p-value

I have some t-values and degrees of freedom and want to find the p-values from them (it's two-tailed). In the real world I would use a t-test table in the back of a Statistics textbook; however, I am using stdtr or stats.t.sf function in python. Both of them work fine for small degrees of freedom but give me nan for large degrees of freedom :

```
pf = 2*stdtr(dof, -np.abs(tf))
pval = 2*stats.t.sf(np.abs(tf), dof-1)
```

tf = -11.374250, dof=-2176568.362223 gives pf and pval= nan.

Can you please help me understand what is happening here internally. Besides, how can read the code for these internal functions of python.

Comment: These are not "internal functions of python"; they are from SciPy. Specifically, they are `scipy.special.stdtr()` and `scipy.stats.t.sf()`. The second one's source code is readily available in iPython via `scipy.stats.t.sf??` -- putting two question marks after a function will often bring-up the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re what happens here internally. Well, the Student t distribution is defined for `dof > 0`, at least in scipy.stats:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html.
Hence a nan:

```
In [11]: stats.t.sf(-11, df=10)
Out[11]: 0.99999967038443183

In [12]: stats.t.sf(-11, df=-10)
Out[12]: nan
```